# Select the records containg multiple semicolons should be replaced by single semicolon but do not update original records

Tags: mysql

I want to select all records having at most one semicolon.

My records contains multiple consigative semicolons should be selected as single semicolons like - `;;;;`, while selection it should be like `;`.

I have table like this:

```
**id  firstname   city**

  1    sachi;;;n   pune
  2    sandip;     pune
  3    ra;;j       mumbai
  4    bu;;;sh     washington
```

---

Result should be like this:

```
**id  firstname   city**

  1    sachi;n   pune
  2    sandip;     pune
  3    ra;j       mumbai
  4    bu;sh     washington
```

Comment: maybe you should post your current code here. are you using PHP ?

Comment: No, I am not using php. I have done this task by using Java.  String str="sachin;;;;;n";        String str1 = str.replaceAll(";;+", ";"); System.out.println("Final String : "+str1);

Answer (score 0):

This would replace with single ';' no matter how many ';' are there.

```
$test = $row['YOUR_COLUMN'];

$output = preg_replace('!\;+!', ';', '$test');
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. But I need solution in the form of MySql query.

Comment: I have created this logic in Java as bellow:- String str="sachin;;;;;n";
  String str1 = str.replaceAll(";;+", ";");
  
  System.out.println("Final String : "+str1);